# What is the purposes and benefits of using stack swapping in x86?

Tags: x86, paging, virtual-memory

I am currently learning x86 virtual memory and paging. But I have some questions when I read about swapping out state. 
Also, when more than one program is allowed to exist, what additional support is need to track stack pointers?

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges.  The operating has a thread scheduler that creates the illusion that multiple processes can execute at the same time.  Even though the processor can execute only a few at the same time, 4 is typical.  One of its jobs is to store the entire processor state when a thread is suspended and restore it when it is re-activated.  The stack pointer is just one small part of that state.

Comment: @JessieLyu, can you clarify what you are actually asking here?

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of gross oversimplification (and ignoring threads)--

A stack is a block of memory referenced by the stack pointer register. There is nothing special about the stack memory. The operating system will set up a stack. However, the user can allocate a block of memory and have the stack pointer point to it.

All you have to do to change the stack is assign a new value to the stack pointer register.

In the old days before OS thread support, user mode thread libraries would set up multiple stacks and switch among them.

From the hardware point of view, the stack is whatever the stack pointer points to.

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

Processors have instructions for saving and loading the process context. That is includes all registers.

All the processor has to do to switch processes (and the stack with it) is to save the current process context and load a new one.

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

There is a separate kernel stack that the operating system uses while the change above is going on.